# An orthonormal sequence in an inner product space converges weakly to $0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

It is a well-known theorem that "An orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space converges weakly to $0$". The proof uses the Bessel's inequality and the Rise representation theorem for which completeness of the space is a necessary condition.

However, I somehow proved the same theorem for any inner product space. If my proof were correct, then textbooks would use that stronger result instead of the current one.

**Theorem:** Let $E$ be an inner product space, $\{ x_n\}$ an orthonormal sequence in an inner product space, and . Then $\{ f(x_n)\}$ converges to $0$ for any $f\in E'$.

**Proof:** Let $f\in E'$. Assume to the contrary that $\{f(x_n)\}$ does not go to $0$. Then there is some $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $\{ x_{k_n}\}$ such that $|f(x_{k_n})|\geq \epsilon $. But then infinitely many of $f(x_{k_n})$'s are positive or they are negative. So without loss of generality, assume that $f(x_{k_n})$'s are all positive. Then $n\cdot \epsilon \leq f(x_{k_1})+...+f(x_{k_n})=| f(x_{k_1})+...+f(x_{k_n})|=|f(x_{k_1}+...+x_{k_n})|\leq ||f||\cdot ||x_{k_1}+...+x_{k_n}||=||f||\cdot \sqrt{n}$ where the last equality follows from the Pythagorean theorem. But we then obtain $||f||\geq \epsilon \cdot \sqrt{n}$, which contradicts with boundedness of $f$. So $f(x_n)\rightarrow 0$. $\square$

I couldn't see the issue here.

Comment: the proof of [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel's_inequality) works also in pre-Hilbert spaces, so you are OK

Comment: But the Riesz representation theorem does not

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is corrrect. You can even generalize it to the complex case by adding a factor $\epsilon_{k_i}$ of modulus $1$ to $x_{k_i}$ so that $f(\epsilon_{k_i}x_{k_i}) > 0$. There’s just not much point, since you could just complete the inner product space to a Hilbert space, so the result for Hilbert spaces implies the result for general inner product spaces anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. But I still have a question. Why then all textbooks uses the Hilbert case rather than this general case? This matters because proofs use the Bessel's inequality and Riesz's representation theorem, which is more complicated than the "natural" proof above.

Comment: @boyler I don't know about "all textbooks". That seems like an exaggeration. When I learned about Hilbert spaces the textbook I used didn't even write down this result, only a more general result saying that for a bounded sequence, weak convergence is equivalent to pointwise convergence on an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @boyler But for those textbooks that do use Bessel's inequality and Riesz's representation theorem, I cannot speak to the author's precise thought process, but I would assume it's just what popped into their mind when they wrote this part of the textbook. After all, the author, writing a textbook on the subject, would have to be quite familiar with it. And for those familiar with Hilbert spaces, Bessel's inequality and Riesz's representation theorem are just matters of basic instincts, applied every day without given much thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to show, basing just on  the  Pythagorean theorem, that $f(e_n)$ is square summable, hence it tends to $0.$ Indeed, we have  $$\left |\sum_{k=1}^nx_kf(e_k)\right |^2= \left |f\left (\sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k\right )\right |^2\\ \le \|f\|^2\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^2$$ Let $x_k=\overline{f(e_k)}.$ Then $$\left (\sum_{k=1}^n|f(e_k)|^2\right )^2\le \|f\|^2\sum_{k=1}^n|f(e_k)|^2$$ Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^n|f(e_k)|^2\le \|f\|^2$$ As $n$ is arbitrary we get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f(e_k)|^2\le \|f\|^2$$